# Running python scripts on windows 10 cmd just by typing python nameofthescript.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, windows-10

I can't run python scripts just by typing `python nameofthescript.py` on Windows 10 `cmd`. The only way to make it work is by typing `python` followed by space and `C:\script\directory\nameofthefile.py`.

I just would like to use a quick way to run python scripts. Already tried to type `py` instead of python.

I've already added the directory to the `PATH` environment variable. Have not been able to find the answer online. If more information is needed to solve the problem, I can try to provide it.

Comment: I don't know if Win10 is any different from Win7 in this respect but with Win7 you just need to set something like `ftype Python.File="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%1" %*` and `assoc .py=Python.File` (from administrator console).  If you also want to not even have to type the .py  extension you can also set `PATHEXT` (from Environment Variable) to include `.PY`

Comment: @tonypdmtr, in general that's wrong in all versions of Windows since XP. CMD's `ftype` and `assoc` commands are from Windows NT 4 (1996) -- before HKCR became a merged view of  "HKCU\Software\Classes" and "HKLM\Software\Classes" that prioritizes the user's HKCU settings. These outdated commands only view/modify "HKLM\Software\Classes". A per-user HKCU setting will trump this. Plus, since Windows 7, the shell implements a locked user choice in a separate, protected registry key. `ftype` does nothing for this. The file association should be managed in the Windows shell, by the shell.

Comment: @ErykSun Wrong or not wrong, it's been working great for me for many many years.

Comment: @tonypdmtr, if so, it's only within the narrow confines of how you install software and configure file associations. Many people end up with a complicated set of progids from multiple installations -- both per-user and per-machine -- including auto-generated progids (e.g. "[HKLM|HKCU]\Software\Classes\Applications\python.exe") -- and a locked in user choice from the "open with" menu. If the user choice happens to be unset, an no conflicting HKCU setting exists, or the user choice is locked on the "Python.File" progid in "HKLM\Software\Classes", then, sure, `ftype` will work.

Comment: @TommasoVasari, you've misunderstood how `PATH` is used. It's a list of directories used by the system to find a file to execute. Python *does not* search `PATH` for the script to open. The path to the script is either fully qualified or the interpreter resolves it against the current working directory. It doesn't go looking all over your filesystem to find it.

Comment: What happens if you just type `nameofthescript.py` at the `cmd` prompt (assuming the current directory is the one containing the file).

Comment: The file extension `.PY` is by default not included in the semicolon separated list of file extensions assigned to __system__ environment variable `PATHEXT` which defines the list of file extensions for executables and scripts which Windows command processor should be aware of if an executable or script is specified in a command line without file extension. Appending `.PY` to existing value of `PATHEXT` makes it possible to execute Python scripts without using explicitly the Python interpreter executable (`python.exe` or `pythonw.exe`) as long as `.py` is associated with the Python executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dpath` is the equivalent to `path` for data files. Type `dpath /?` note it was once called `append` and the help hasn't been updated.

That answers your question as you've asked.

Perhaps you should have asked **how do I just type my script name**?

So

associate `.py` with the python interpreter.

Use commands `ftype` and `assoc`

```
ftype PythonScript=c:\pathtofolder\python.exe %*

assoc .py=PythonScript
```

Then add your SCRIPT path to the path command

```
Setx path "%path%;C:\MyPythonScriptFolder"

Set path=%path%;C:\MyPythonScriptFolder"
```

Then tell windows command prompt to assume .py files are executable so it will search the path for it.

```
Set pathext=%pathext%;.py
```

Comment: The line `Setx path "%path%;C:\MyPythonScriptFolder"` corrupts the __user__ environment variable `PATH`. It is an absolute NO GO - NEVER EVER - to use `%path%` on modifying __user__ or __system__ `PATH` with command `setx` for several reasons. It is much better to modify __user__ `PATH` via Windows __Control Panel - System - Advanced system settings - Environment Variables__ instead of using such a command line corrupting __user__ `PATH` setting. There is also a `"` missing left to `path` on `set path=` to be valid with `Set "path=%path%;C:\MyPythonScriptFolder"` updating __local__ `PATH`.

Comment: Except it doesn't as setx doesn't duplicate path entries. It is special cased.

Comment: CMD's internal `dpath` command has nothing to do with how external commands such as python.exe search for files specified on their command line. Windows has no `exec` system call (other than the joke user-mode emulation function provided by MSVC) that takes `argv` array, so parsing the command line and resolving paths in arguments for external programs is not handled by the shell. Windows only has `CreateProcessW`, which takes an unparsed command line string. Every program parses its own command line.

Comment: I wrote two comments on the question about how and why `assoc` and `ftype` are generally wrong in modern Windows.

Comment: @Mark, no, Mofi is right. `Setx path "%path%;C:\MyPythonScriptFolder"` makes a mess of the per-user "Path" value in "HKCU\Environment". The entire concatenated and expanded value is stored in the per-user value. By expanded I mean all carefully used `REG_SZ` user variables and system variables are replaced with their expanded text values, which ruins the templated structure. But since it's already hideously merging in the per-system value where it doesn't belong, expanding the variables is the least of its problems.

Comment: So how could I possibly do what @Fred explained without messing up my system or user PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Your command prompt should be in the folder with the file in it. Eg, if you `cd C:\script\directory` then you could  `python nameofthescript.py`

Comment: Works in that case but i have to specify everytime the exact directory which is quite long; the solution could be just moving the folder with all my .py in C:\Users\Tommaso\NewScriptFolder\ but i was wondering why (since the folder i keep my scripts in is added to the PATH) it doesn't find the file just by typing python and filename.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your file has permission to be executed. I'm not familiar with Windows, but on Linux it's `chmod +x name_of_file.py`, or with sudo, if you need root privileges. Also, check your python default version, because in most cases python calls python2.7 and not python3...